# Generic Foreign Keys in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin, generic-foreign-key

Is it possible to filter by `GenericForeignKey` object titles in the Django admin?

I want to filter by program name, either `NonSupportedProgram.title` or `SupportedProgram.title` (`list_filter = (SOME FIELD HERE)`), but can't figure out how?

models.py

```
class FullCitation(models.Model):
    # the software to which this citation belongs
    # either a supported software program or a non-supported software program
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class NonSupportedProgram(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank = True)
    full_citation = generic.GenericRelation('FullCitation')

class SupportedProgram(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank = True)
    full_citation = generic.GenericRelation('FullCitation')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic Relations/Generic Foreign Keys in the Django Admin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28308980/generic-relations-generic-foreign-keys-in-the-django-admin)

Comment: No, not the same because here I'm trying to use the `GenericForeignKey` field as an argument in `ModelAdmin.list_filter` and/or `ModelAdmin.search_fields`. I don't know how (or if it's possible) to use the search and/or filter methods of ModelAdmin to seach/filter by the name of my `GenericForeignKey` objects...?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use a SimpleListFilter and define your own queryset so that you can get your own results.

More info here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter

```
class YourCustomListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
   title = 'By Program Name'
   parameter_name = 'program'

   def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
       return(
           ('supported','Supported Programs'),
           ('nonsupported', 'Non-Supported Programs')
       )

   def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value() == 'supported':
            return queryset.filter(supported__isnull=False)
        if self.value() == 'nonsupported':
            return queryset.filter(nonsupported__isnull=False)

admin.py
list_filter = (YourCustomListFilter,)
```

You will need to add related_query_name='supported' and related_query_name='nonsupported' on your GenericRelation declaration to allow querying from the related objects.

More info on querying GenericRelations here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations

This should be a little push on the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

One way I see fit is the following:

You could change your models to the following:

```
class FullCitaton(models.Model):
    # Any Model Fields you want...
    program = ForeignKey('Program')

class Program(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank = True)
    is_supported = models.NullBooleanField()
```

Note that both `SupportedProgram` and `NonSupportedProgram` are in the same `Progam` model right now. The way to differ them is through the `is_supported` `NullBoolean` field.
Then, all you have to do is queryth `Program` model using the title field.
Now, maybe you didn't do it this way because you have another issue I'm unable to see right now. But, anyway, this should work.

Cheers!